# ADO.NET entity data model deleting many rows

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I have following structure of the database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `klienci` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazwa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `miejscowosc` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `klienci_do_trasy` (
  `klient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trasa_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seq` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`klient_id`,`trasa_id`),
  KEY `trasa_id` (`trasa_id`),
  KEY `klient_id` (`klient_id`,`trasa_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trasy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazwa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `klienci_do_trasy`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `klienci_do_trasy_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`klient_id`) REFERENCES `klienci` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `klienci_do_trasy_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`trasa_id`) REFERENCES `trasy` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

And I would like to run query similar to:

```
DELETE FROM klienci_do_trasy WHERE klient_id = 1;
```

Don't know how to do this with ADO.NET entity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With EntityFramework v1.0 there is no such a possibility. You would have to call ObjectContext.DeleteObject for each entity:

```
 using (TheDataContext entities = new TheDataContext())
  {
        List<Klienci_do_tracy> kdcList = //get entities to delete
        foreach(Klienci_do_tracy kdc in kdcList)
        {
             entities.DeleteObject(kdc);
        }
        entities.SaveChanges();
  }
```

or you could use [EntityCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitycommand.aspx) to do that on old fashion way.

**[update: run native sql with EF]**

```
var eConnection = (System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)yourContextInstance.Connection;

DbConnection conn = eConnection.StoreConnection;

 if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
      conn.Open();  
 using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
       {
        //write native sql query
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from...where...";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
```

You would probably have to wrap this in try finally to ensure closing connection if something goes wrong and additional checks on connestion state.

Comment: How to do that if my context is: korlenEntities2 _db = new korlenEntities2();

            System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand com = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand();
            com.Connection = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection("name=korlenEntities2");
            com.Connection.Open();
            com.CommandText = "DELETE VALUE FROM klienci_do_trasy";
            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

does not work and require manual opening connection :(

Comment: Sorry Inez, I mislead you when saying to use EntityCommand. Look updated answer to see how to run native query with ef.

Comment: Misha, do you know how to do this with EF4?

Comment: No Inez, still didn't have time to take a deeper look in EF4. Sorry.